# When should you use textual "or, and, not" over symbolic "||, &&, !" logical operators in JSP EL?

Tags: jsp, el

The textual versions may improve readability for non-programmers, but otherwise I can't imagine any differentiators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From symbolic ones the `&&` is syntactically invalid in XML (JSPX, Facelets), because it's a reserved XML character. You'd prefer the textual one in EL then. Since consistency is a good thing, you'd like to do the same for other operators.

By the way, the `empty` operator doesn't have a direct symbolic counterpart since it not only tests on `null`, but also on empty string (or collection size). Most close would be:

```
${var == null && fn:length(var) == 0}
```

The argument for `empty` would then be that it is less typing and doesn't require JSTL functions.